# Memory Limit Reached When Switching Currency

Tags: currency

I have a strange bug, wonder if anyone can help.

**Scenario**

- have an empty cart
- switch to euros
- Loads fine
- Add a product to cart
- Loads fine
- Switch back to pounds
- Site hangs and then crashes
- Site cant be reloaded until all cookies are deleted

**Error Message**

> [Thu Jun 12 12:11:56.419992 2014] [:error] [pid 2652] [client xxx] PHP
>   Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 7 bytes) in /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line
>   290

As you can see my memory limit is 1024m  which is WAY more than enough, so it must be something else :/ just not sure what.

Thoughts?

**Installed Modules**

```
AW_All
AW_Kbase
AlanCole_CouponFix
AlanCole_GooglePS
AlanCole_LiveChat
AlanCole_PackingSlip
AlanCole_QuickOrder
AlanCole_QuickbooksIntergration
AlanCole_StoreLocator
Amasty_Oaction
Aschroder_SMTPPro
Cm_RedisSession
CommerceExtensions_Core
CommerceExtensions_Mergecustomers
Ebizmarts_AbandonedCart
Ebizmarts_Autoresponder
Ebizmarts_MageMonkey
Ebizmarts_Mandrill
Ebizmarts_SagePayReporting
Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite
EmjaInteractive_OrderAssign
Ezmage_OscommerceImport
Fishpig_Wordpress
Fishpig_Wordpress_Addon_AddThis
Fishpig_Wordpress_Addon_LightboxGallery
Fishpig_Wordpress_Addon_WordPressSEO
Fishpig_Wordpress_Addon_Yarpp
Fishpig_Wordpress_FPAdmin
Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus
Innoexts_Core
Innoexts_CurrencyPricing
JeroenVermeulen_Solarium
Magemaven_OrderComment
MagenThemes_MTColinusAdmin
MagenThemes_Mtslideshow
Magneto_Debug
Meanbee_Shippingrules
Meanbee_Tinymce5
Phoenix_Moneybookers
PostcodeAnywhere_CapturePlus
Shweta_Ajaxcoupon
Webshopapps_Matrixrate
```

Comment: Do you have any code customizations with regards to currencies or cart?
Or is this a plain Magento install?

Comment: I have a custom module on the cart update observer, turned that off and still get this. We're also running about 40 other modules. I've added a list above...

Comment: try disabling other modules as well

Comment: step one by one through all 42 modules seems a little hard core, my site will stop functioning after a few disables anyway. There has to be a better method for working this out?

Comment: Has this been solved? I have the same issue on my site. Extensions in common:- AW_All Ebizmarts_SagePayReporting Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus Phoenix_Moneybookers Webshopapps_Matrixrate

Comment: Nope, that is the cost of using so many extensions. You can copy the site and test on another instance of it, that's just the way it goes, badly behaved extensions cause all these types of problems. We would say to put you on a very high spec server with high memory to test, but you probably have budget constraints, so back to testing the plugins one by one. Currency may be a red herring, the checkout  is the most resource intensive process so it could be related to the item in the cart.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
memory_limit to 512M in
```

> htaccess

Or

`ini_set("memory_limit", “512M");` in

> index.php

file

Comment: 'msp' is a reference to a custom module...one I do not have.

Comment: Probably best to reference the original post here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/667076/#t466834

Comment: Its always better to share the code then links, because links may break or may not work.

Comment: Either way in this case, the code just isn't relevant. But thanks for trying.

Comment: Not good, lets just all debug together again

Comment: Answer updated please try this

Comment: I appreciate the help here, but just guessing at answers or stripping answers from the MC forums isn't massively helpful :/ my memory limit is being set to 512M you can see that from the error message.

Comment: As you are using modules, what best I can do is share my thoughts, I have hence updated

Comment: User9123 - I've *definitely* seen this before on a site I've worked on, but I can't find the solution. Currently back-tracking through lots of commits :)

Comment: TBI, thank you for trying.

Douglas, Thanks :)

Comment: Tried this in php.ini

extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so

?

Comment: Is this issue fixed?

Comment: it not good  idea to increase memory limit...........disable one by one module and Check Which extension is create issue.Then check where the issue

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you use subpar templates, or whoever built the theme was not following the Way of Magento. Often everything seems to work just fine at first, but at some point things starting to fall apart at random moments, usually with memory limit errors (for example, I don't think the switch itself is culprit in your case).

Vinai Kopp wrote a great article about scalability you should check. Perhaps it helps you to find the real reason why you run out of memory:

http://vinaikopp.com/2014/06/09/preloading-for-scalabiliy/